# firebase remote config not working on 4G network

Tags: android, firebase, 3g, 4g, firebase-remote-config

For some reason remoteConfig won't work on my 4G network (and i assume other networks like 3G etc). On wifi it works fine.

onComplete is called, but task.isSuccessful = false.

Trying to log task.getException().getMessage() returns null

Anyone any idea how to solve this issue. I really need to get remoteConfig running on 3G/4G networks, etc.

This is on Android btw. testing on a HUAWEI android 5.1 device

Comment: I have the same problem! (disclaimer collegue of Rik : D)

Comment: Maybe `FirebaseRemoteConfig.getInstance().getInfo().getLastFetchStatus()` will provide a clue.  Values are [listed here](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/firebase/remoteconfig/FirebaseRemoteConfig).

Comment: Attaching the relevant code you are using for initialize firebase remote config could help

Comment: Hey did you get any work around on this?